# Entering a lock in an iterator block

Tags: c#, iterator, spinlock

I am curious to know if an iterator block is a good place to lock.

I have this method:

```
protected SpinLock readLock;
protected bool readLockTaken;
protected SpinLock writeLock;
protected bool writeLockTaken;

public IEnumerator<T> GetConsumingEnumerator()
{
    readLock.Enter(ref writeLockTaken);

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.Count; i++)
        {
            if(queue.Count != 0)
                yield return queue.Dequeue();
            else
                yield break;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        readLock.Exit();
    }            
}
```

I don't have much experience with iterator blocks and am wondering if the lock will stay "entered" for the duration of, say, a statement like this:

```
foreach(T thing in ThingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerator())
{
    ...
}
```

Also, if I use LINQ to get n elements, where `n < "collection".Count` as follows:

```
foreach(T thing in ThingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerator().Take(n))
{
    ...
}
```

Will the spinlock stay locked while the elements are accessed? Or will the lock exit and re-enter for each iteration?

Comment: did you test it, it should be rather easy to prove/disprove this in a debugger.

Comment: [This might be of interest](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/10/23/iterating-atomically/)

Comment: @Crowcoder That's about a single iterator being shared between two threads, rather than two iterators, each used in a single (different) thread, but that are both using some shared resource to determine what item each yields.  The latter is a much simpler problem than the former.

Comment: If you run this code and it ends up holding the lock, how are you going to ensure that none of the consumers of your code are going to access any other locks between calls to "MoveNext", ending up with deadlocks as a result of multiple nested locks being taken out inadvertently?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "intended". Semantically everything's on the up and up, but you *are* making the assumption that the `foreach` loops will be "fast". There's no reason they should be. If enumerating the collection is going to be a synchronization bottleneck, you probably shouldn't offer the enumeration as an option, but write a lock-free implementation or force clients to copy. I, for one, would not find the idea of a "consuming enumerator" natural at all -- enumeration is prototypically something that is free of side effects. (One-time enumerables are not quite the same thing.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert actually the idea of a consuming enumerator was implemented a while ago by Ms in 'ConcurrentQueue'.

Comment: @Servy I edited my question. Are you saying that the lock is entered and exited on each iteration? My hope was that the lock would stay entered until all iterations are complete.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart No, I'm saying that if you hold onto the lock between calls to `MoveNext` you need to ensure that your consumers aren't creating deadlocks with whatever code they're running.  Running some arbitrary code that you have no control over while holding onto a lock is a recipe for deadlocks.